# Parsing a PySpark Dataframe column with non-consistent delimiters

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am dealing with a column in my data which has values which roughly look like:

```
"In: Cook (12), Doctor (2) @ New York, Teacher (1) @ Chicago Out: Total: Cook (15), Doctor (5), Teacher (3) @ New York, Teacher (1) @ Chicago"
```

(The `Out:` section in this case is just blank, otherwise it has same format as `In:`)

The entire above string is just stuffed into one column

Each column tracks the Inflow, Outflow, and total counts of different professions at different locations.

I'm relatively new to PySpark, and I'm trying to avoid looping through the columns counting tokens, which is what I might do if I was just text processing in Python, but even then, I'm not sure what the best way to parse this is.

I've successfully parsed and exploded columns that only have 1 location for `In/Out/Total`, but the splitting for multiple locations is what's problematic for me

My goal is to explode these out into their own columns and rows with a structure somewhat like:

| Profession | Count | Location | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cook | 12 | New York | In |
| doctor | 2 | New York | In |
| teacher | 1 | Chicago | In |

The data is structured enough that I know it's possible, I'm just at my limit of what I understand how to do in PySpark/Regex.

If useful, Professions/Locations could be reasonably enumerated beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `regexp_replace`, `regexp_extract` along with `split` and `transform` functions.

1. Extract `In` and `Out` into separate columns using regex
2. In order to be able to split the strings using comma, we need to replace the commas that come just after a parentheses `)` by `;`
3. Transform both the resulting arrays `in` and `out` to get a array of struct elements `struct(profession, location, direction)` and union the transformed arrays
4. Inline the array of structs and explode the array of professions
5. Extract `Profession` and `Count` using regex

Example using the provided string (suppose the column is named `value`):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df1 = df.withColumn(
    "in",
    F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_extract("value", "In:(.*) Out:", 1), r"\),", r"\);"), ",")
).withColumn(
    "out",
    F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_extract("value", "Out:(.*) Total:", 1), r"\),", r"\);"), ",")
).withColumn(
    "value",
    F.array_union(
        F.expr("transform(in, x -> struct(split(split(x, '@')[0], ';') as Profession, split(x, '@')[1] as Location, 'in' as Direction))"),
        F.expr("transform(out, x -> struct(split(split(x, '@')[0], ';') as Profession, split(x, '@')[1] as Location, 'out' as Direction))")
    )
).selectExpr("inline(value)").withColumn(
    "Profession",
    F.explode("Profession")
).select(
    F.regexp_extract("Profession", r"(.*)\(\d+\)", 1).alias("Profession"),
    F.regexp_extract("Profession", r".*\((\d+)\)", 1).alias("Count"),
    "Location",
    "Direction"
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+----------+-----+---------+---------+
#|Profession|Count|Location |Direction|
#+----------+-----+---------+---------+
#| Cook     |12   | New York|in       |
#| Doctor   |2    | New York|in       |
#| Teacher  |1    | Chicago |in       |
#|          |     |null     |out      |
#+----------+-----+---------+---------+
```

You may need some additional steps to handle spaces (trim) and null values.